# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

```
parent_folder/
    __init__.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        mymodule.py
    mycode/
        __init__.py
        mycode.py
```

mymodule.py:

```
def myfun():
    print("Hello world")
```

mycode.py:

```
from mypackage.mymodule import myfun  
myfun()
```

When i run mycode.py, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage' pops up.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you try `from ../mypackage.mymodule import myfun`

Comment: How do you run mycode.py ?

Comment: C:\Users\Juampi\Desktop\parent_folder\mycode>python mycode.py

Comment: ../mypackage.mymodule import myfun does not work

Comment: Thats the problem , you need to add `parent_folder` path to `sys.path` variable, before trying to do `from mypackage.mymodule import myfun` .

Comment: @ksai was almost there: `from ..mypackage.mymodule import myfun`.

Comment: Don't run it like this: `C:\Users\Juampi\Desktop\parent_folder\mycode>python mycode.py`. You're now running a script that lives inside a package. That is bad structuring. A script should live outside any package (there are other things you could do, like running a module with the `-m` switch, but that's for a next stage).

Comment: @Evert You are right